# dim(X) must have a positive length (cumsum)

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I'm running the following section of code that includes a loop:

```
i <- 1 #defined as 1 earlier in the code
CancCheck <- data.frame()     #Blank data frame
for (i in 1:iForeper+1) {
CancCheck[i,1]<-i-1
CancCheck[i,2]<- sum(CancNP[CancNP[,7]==i-1,4]) # aggregate all rooms with same cancellation window
}
CancCheck[,3]<- apply(CancCheck[,2],2,cumsum)
```

the loop appears to run without issue (columns 1 and 2 are populated), however I receive the following error relating to the last line:

```
Error in apply(CancCheck[, 2], 2, cumsum) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

The function should "Compute cumulative sums of
columns of matrix".  I'm not clear on what it defines as the "dim (x)" that it is not positive.

Below are the dput() for CancCheck and CancNP:

```
iForeper <- 200
```

CancCheck

```
>dput(head(CancCheck,20))
structure(list(V1 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19), V2 = c(NA, 1077L, 1713L, 2631L, 
3204L, 3697L, 3802L, 3789L, 3784L, 3554L, 3170L, 3059L, 2989L, 
2919L, 2676L, 2608L, 2281L, 2340L, 2164L, 2137L), V3 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

CancNP

```
> dput(head(CancNP,20))
structure(list(bookingdata.Cancellation.Date = structure(c(16036, 
16036, 16036, 16036, 16036, 16031, 16031, 16031, 16031, 16031, 
16031, 16031, 16031, 15986, 15986, 15986, 15986, 15986, 15986, 
15986), class = "Date"), bookingdata.Arrival.Date = structure(c(16070, 
16068, 16058, 16052, 16049, 16052, 16049, 16043, 16039, 16038, 
16037, 16036, 16033, 16022, 16021, 16007, 16002, 16016, 16006, 
16003), class = "Date"), bookingdata.Creation.Date = structure(c(16027, 
16027, 16027, 16027, 16027, 16028, 16028, 16028, 16028, 16028, 
16028, 16028, 16028, 15986, 15986, 15986, 15986, 15986, 15986, 
15986), class = "Date"), bookingdata.Room.nights = c(37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), CFBMD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), FBWRMD = structure(c(-1, 
-3, -13, -19, -22, -19, -22, -28, -32, -33, -34, -35, -38, -49, 
-50, -64, -69, -55, -65, -68), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    V7 = structure(c(34, 32, 22, 16, 13, 21, 18, 12, 8, 7, 6, 
    5, 2, 36, 35, 21, 16, 30, 20, 17), class = "difftime", units = "days")), .Names = c("bookingdata.Cancellation.Date", 
"bookingdata.Arrival.Date", "bookingdata.Creation.Date", "bookingdata.Room.nights", 
"CFBMD", "FBWRMD", "V7"), row.names = c(202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 
206L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 313L, 314L, 
315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just `CancCheck[,3]<- cumsum(CancCheck[,2])` ?

Comment: `CancCheck[, 2]` is in fact a vector so you can't take his dimension (it is NULL)

Comment: it would be great if you could give us `dput(cancCheck)` and your expected output for the third column.

Comment: Hi Etienne. I had previously tried `cumsum(CancCheck[,2])` (which i understand is appropriate as it is a vector), it returned a third column, however entirely filled with NA values.

Comment: then please give us `dput(CancCheck)` and  `dput(CancNP)` and the value of `iForeper`

Comment: Etienne, my apologies, but how do I share the created file here with you?

Comment: you don't need to share it just paste the output of `dput`. If your data is too big put the output of `dput(head(yourData,20))`

Comment: I follow, thank you.  Please find the outputs as an edit in the original question.

Comment: and what would be the first rows of your desired output for the 3 columns of CancCheck ?

Comment: yeah, you need to be clear on exactly what it is that you need. Replicable data and desired final results

Comment: Apologies for delayed response, I have answered the question and posted  said answer below.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to those helpful responders for my delayed reply; this has now been solved.

The aim was for column 3 of CancCheck (`CancCheck[,3]`) to produce a cumulative sum of the values in column 2 (`CancCheck[,2]`). The first row of CancCheck contained NA values, prohibiting the function from working - thus it needed to be removed.

Using `CancCheck = CancCheck[-1,]` the first row containing NA's was removed, leaving the required populated rows.  As the user "etienne" mentioned previously,  `CancCheck[,3]<- cumsum(CancCheck[,2])` is the correct way to take the cumulative sum for a vector, and thus I achieved the desired output with the final code:

```
i <- 1 #defined as 1 earlier in the code
CancCheck <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:iForeper+1) {
CancCheck[i,1]<-i-1
CancCheck[i,2]<- sum(CancNP[CancNP[,7]==i-1,4]) # % aggregate all rooms with same cancellation window
}
CancCheck = CancCheck[-1,] #Removes first row, containing NA values
CancCheck[,3] <- cumsum(CancCheck[,2]) #Cumulative Density`


> head(CancCheck)
  V1   V2    V3
2  1 1077  1077
3  2 1713  2790
4  3 2631  5421
5  4 3204  8625
6  5 3697 12322
7  6 3802 16124
```